# Explanation of Code - I think it's Lambda expression

Tags: javascript, lambda

It's been long since i have been a programmer but i sometimes i just ask stupid questions.
I have not some new techniques which make me pretty old fashioned programmer. For example the following code, is to remove all cookies.

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    var cookie = cookies[i];
    var eqPos = cookie.indexOf('=');
    var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
    document.cookie = name + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT';
}
```

In there it is doing this

```
eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
```

i don't know what is happening here. Could you please explain. And what is this type of notation and what  do i need to learn to understand it.

Comment: It's a ternary operator meaning `if (eqPos > -1) cookie.substr(0, eqPos); else cookie;` and the result gets assigned to `name`.

Comment: Further to C5H8NNaO4's comment, it is not a lambda expression. The ternary operator is also known as the conditional operator. Further information with example usage is available [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a short if statment, 
this is the condition

```
eqPos > -1
```

name  will be:

```
cookie.substr(0, eqPos)
```

if the condition is true:

and

```
cookie
```

If it is false